# How to extract data from json in uwp

Tags: json, uwp

Hi I'am getting a json as response below. Now I want to extract each data and need to insert to sqlite table. How can I loop through each json data?

```
 private async System.Threading.Tasks.Task SyncAsync()
    {
        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        { 
            client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:56666/");
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
            HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync("Api/student");

            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                var stdetails=response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            }
         }
      }
```

Resulted json :

```
[{"ID":1,"name":"Shyam","class":"a"},{"ID":2,"name":"Bran","class":"b"}]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a class representing your JSON object, in your case -

```
public class MyModel 
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string @class { get; set; }
}
```

And then use below line to deserialize the data into required classes

```
var jsonData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<MyModel>>(stdetails);
```

Comment: how can I see the value of this class after assigning json to jsonData?

Comment: Your json data is a collection of MyModel object class and it will be stored in jsonData variable. You can directly access by using like 


var firstObject = jsonData.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == 1);

Comment: Can I directly use this jsonData to insert to sqlite table?

Comment: Your query is very broad, the jsondata is a c# collection property, you can use it anywhere like you do any object. Obviously, you can use it to pass data to sqllite, depends on how you have created your sqllite library calls

Comment: Why did you use the "@" char before "class" property?

Comment: Because class is a keyword in c# and you cannot use a keyword as an identifier, as your JSON has a property named class @ is used to map it to same.